# How to separate a border and an effect?

Tags: javafx, javafx-css

Currently, I have a button with the following CSS:

```
Button {
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-color-text;
    -fx-font: 15pt "Raleway SemiBold";

    -fx-background-color: -fx-color-theme;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-padding: 4px 20px;
    /* -fx-effect: innershadow(two-pass-box, white, 2, 0.2, 0, 0); */
    -fx-border-insets: 0;
    -fx-border-color: black;
}
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

And I'm trying to add an inner shadow to the button. I want the border to show on the *outside* of this button, which should result in something like this:

[image]

I made that in Swing. However, when I try and apply my inner shadow, it draws on top of my border, as shown:

[image]

I've tried setting the border insets to -1 (because there isn't an insets property for the effect), but that just moved the effect with it:

[image]

My question is: What can I do to ensure that I can see my border around the outside, but keep my effect on the inside?

EDIT: I'm pretty sure that this is a bug in OpenJFX and I've submitted a bug report. Here's some quick code you can use to reproduce the issue:

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Region example = new Region();
        example.setMaxWidth(100);
        example.setMaxHeight(100);
        example.setEffect(new InnerShadow(BlurType.GAUSSIAN, Color.RED, 10, 0.04, 0, 0));
        example.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white; -fx-border-color: BLUE; -fx-border-width: 5px;");

        StackPane container = new StackPane();
        container.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
        container.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        container.getChildren().add(example);

        Scene scene = new Scene(container, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

EDIT2: This is end up being a bug, and it's been reported here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8238733

Comment: try  -fx-effect: innershadow( gaussian , rgba(0,0,0,0.7) , 20,0,0,0 );

Comment: @Ahamed Safnaj That adds a very unnoticeable vignette effect around the button, but does not fix the issue

Comment: I would suggest jfoenix material library for javafx. It has very attractive buttons. If you wish you can check them out too..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the border is getting blended with the effect which is applied. And as you are pretty sure that it could be a bug in JavaFX rendering, below is one way to get it look the way you want.

You can consider the below solution as when you think like "**I definitely want this look only !!**" kind of thing :)

The idea is, instead of setting the effect, you paint the effect manually.

```
.button {
    -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;
    -fx-font: 15pt "Raleway SemiBold";
    -fx-background-color: #000000, #720D4D, #D03A9A, #DD70B6, #B01378, #CC2C93, #D03A9A, #C81688;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 1 2 2 1, 1 2 2 2, 2, 2 3 3 2, 2 3 3 3, 3;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-padding: 4px 20px;
    -fx-border-insets: 0px;
    -fx-border-radius: 0px;
    -fx-border-width: 0px;
}
```

And the output is as below [ignore the font as I dont have the .tff ;)]:

[image]

And a closer look for verification purpose:

[image]

This may not be an actual solution, but can be one alternate (least case).

Comment: I was afraid it'd be a bug. I'll let this question play out and if this is the only solution I'll mark this as the solution. Thanks the this alternative, I'll check it out.

Comment: Very late reply, but this issue did end up being bug and it's been reported here. Accepting your answer as the solution :)

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8238733